# jquery calendar and mootools conflict

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have been pulling my hair out

I need the two plugins to work together

below is my code stripped back

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitarald.de/js/mootools-1.2-core-nc.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitarald.de//project/autocompleter/1-1/source/Observer.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitarald.de//project/autocompleter/1-1/source/Autocompleter.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitarald.de//project/autocompleter/1-1/source/Autocompleter.Local.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/auto-city.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/datepicker.jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <br />

                            <form action="">
                                    <input type="text" id="ap-city" value="From" size="16" class="text" />
                            </form>

            <br />

                            <form action="">
                                <input class="datepicker" type="hidden" />
                            </form>

            </body>

            </html>
```

top five scripts are for the autocomplete - the bottom two are for the calendar. I  can only get one or the other working. There is obv a conflict but I have no idea how to make the  $.noConflict(): work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your main (not the libs) JavaScript file:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: Hey, i appreciate the quick response. just to clarify - do you mean add this inside the jquery.min.js file

Comment: Hey PeeHaa, I am a bit out of my depth so please excuse me. I added this to datepicker.jquery.min.js but it caused an error. Where specifically should I add this?

Comment: I have used the example but still get errors. I am using Jquery datepicker and mootools auto complete. There is no javascript in the actual html markup apart from the references to the js files in the head of the document. I am a php guy so js is not so easy. Where should I be referencing this - $.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here. }); - should I be putting the js from my datepicker.jquery.min.js file in the middle

Comment: @Jeff: You should have a file with your own js code somewhere.

Comment: I have edited my post and added a stripped back version of the mark up I am using. As you can see, its two input forms that trigger the js

Comment: addd this to the datepicker.jquery.min.js file:                 jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
       js code in here    });
}); - I also put bth my jquery scripts in the header above the mootools script. Thanks for all feedback

Answer (score 0):

Use namespacing. [See this for an example](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools)

Comment: thanks for this - I need more info. I have looked at the examples on the jquery site but cant make any real sense of it. - I am only referencing js files in the head of my html - there is no javascript in the actual markup like the examples use.